# convert 4 byte array into integer then convert integer into time

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to find creation time and modification time. If I have an array of bytes then I convert 4 byte into an integer. How to convert the integer into time?

```
byte []a = new byte [8];

a[0] = 5;
a[1] = 8;
a[2] = 0;
a[3] = 19;
a[4] = 77;
a[5] = 54;
a[6] = 0;
a[7] = 9;

//convert byte into integer

Int32 creationtime = BitConverter.ToInt32(a,0);


Int32 modificationtime = BitConverter.ToInt32(a, 4);
```

Comment: How do you define 'time'? How should this conversation happen?

Comment: creationtime is 318769157. What kind of date is this?

Comment: Trying to find any kind of sense in the numbers... The modification time seems to be a lot lower than the creation time. How could it be modified before it was created?

Comment: is DateTime.FromBinary what you're after ?

Comment: I want to find creation time and modification time in date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very unclear but in order to convert a byte array into an integer array you can use LINQ this way :

```
var IntArray = ByteArray.Select(x=> Convert.ToInt16(x)).ToArray();
```

And to turn integers to time you can use :

```
foreach (var i in IntArray) {
TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromHours(i); // or maybe from seconds, etc
}
```

Comment: ok thank you but "Timespan" not declare in my program and ignore it

Comment: Sorry it is TimeSpan. I've just edited my answer. With T and S in uppercase.

Comment: ok with great thanks for you but I try this code on array{33,57,200,260} this code fail and not run program .........I need to use large number in array and convert it to time ,can u help me when use array with large number like array{33,57,200,260}??

Comment: Well, the Byte can only contain values in a specific range. If you wanna use larger number you have to use Integers. I don't know for what reasons you are using Bytes but I would recommend you to use an Integer list instead. The Integers can be no longer that 64 bits anyway, otherwise there would be an integer overflow. You can add greater details in your question if you still experiencing any problem.

Comment: i can not use integer array but i make small program with array has value {{33,57,200,260} this array of byte then convert it to integer but when i use your code "TimeSpam" ,it ignore and not run program .is there another method??

Comment: Well, the 260 cannot be a Byte and this is the problem.

Comment: Byte value should be 0 to 255

Comment: ok sorry for this, array{33,157,245,200}